# Windows 2003 stop one update installing

Tags: windows, automatic-updates

I have a windows 2003 server with multiple updates downloaded and ready to install. I want to stop one of the updates installing but there doesn’t appear to be any option, just the install button.

Answer (score -1):

You can select which update if you select **custom**

[image]

For cancelling update that are installing, in Windows server 2003 it can happen on update that cant be cancelled. Like major update like a service pack and such.

Leave it time to finish, if it can't finish you have no choice exept kill by task manager the install, but be warned it can leave you with other errors after.

Please read that article too about 2003, as it's a really bad situation to run 2003  now.

[Risks of Running Windows Server 2003 Beyond End-Of-Life: It's Time to Act. What's Your Action Plan?](http://m.windowsitpro.com/blog/risks-running-windows-server-2003-beyond-end-life-its-time-act-whats-your-action-plan)

Comment: I don’t want to cancel the update I want to prevent it installing. I am at the MS update web page with an Install button and a list of updates. There doesn’t appear to be any option to selectively install the updates, I need to remove one update from the list before installing.

Comment: @user2369812 on IE? as usually you can uncheck an update, unless its a requierement for other update

Comment: On IE yes, but there is no option to uncheck

Comment: @user2369812 What update its?